# nopCommerce multistore enable/disable functionaliity not working when multiple control with different id's

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I am using nopCommerce 3.40

I am using multistore functionality in my nopCommerce plugin. and i have some issue on multistore default script.

```
<tr>
        <td class="adminTitle">
        @Html.OverrideStoreCheckboxFor(model => model.Customer_OverrideForStore, model => model.Customer, Model.ActiveStoreScopeConfiguration)
        @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.Customer):</td>
        <td class="adminData">
            <div class="leftsidebox">
                <div class="leftsideboxCheckbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerEnable)
                </div>
                <div class="leftsideboxTextarea">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Customer)<br />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rightsidebox">
                <div class="rightsideboxCheckbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StoreOwnerEnable)
                </div>
                <div class="rightsideboxTextarea">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.StoreOwner)<br />
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I have four control like CustomerEnable(check box), Customer(textbox), StoreOwnerEnable(check box), StoreOwner(text box).

Multistore enable/disable is only working on single control like on this control @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Customer)

but i want to all my four control enable/disable when i click on @Html.OverrideStoreCheckboxFor() check box.

Thanks in advance.

Ragards,
Jatin

Answer (score 0):

if you want that your all control should be accepted by multistore then you have to write `OverrideStoreCheckboxFor` for all your properties. Have a look at the default **Plugins -> Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider -> Views -> WidgetsNivoSlider -> Configure.cshtml** plugin view.

```
    <tr>
        <td class="adminTitle">
        @Html.OverrideStoreCheckboxFor(model => model.Picture1Id_OverrideForStore, model => model.Picture1Id, Model.ActiveStoreScopeConfiguration)
            @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.Picture1Id):
        </td>
        <td class="adminData">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Picture1Id)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Picture1Id)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="adminTitle">
        @Html.OverrideStoreCheckboxFor(model => model.Text1_OverrideForStore, model => model.Text1, Model.ActiveStoreScopeConfiguration)
            @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.Text1):
        </td>
        <td class="adminData">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Text1)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Text1)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="adminTitle">
        @Html.OverrideStoreCheckboxFor(model => model.Link1_OverrideForStore, model => model.Link1, Model.ActiveStoreScopeConfiguration)
            @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.Link1):
        </td>
        <td class="adminData">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Link1)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Link1)
        </td>
    </tr>
```